# Make jQuery act dynamically depending on the width of the window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello! I've been learning jQuery for a little while now and am trying to sharpen my skills by creating a responsive website. I added a navigation bar, then a big slider, and below it is the main content of the website. Right now, jQuery (as both the menu background and the main background are black) adds a class to the navigation bar in order to turn it white as soon as you scroll past the slider (which has a height of 550px), so it will be easier to read.

Here's the thing: I want jQuery to add that class depending on the width of the window. If it's **less** than 600px wide, I want the class to be added automatically. Otherwise, I want jQuery to add it as soon as you scroll past the slider (since I hide it when the window is less than 600px wide). My code is below, and it works just fine if I resize the window and then refresh the page, but I want it to add the class dynamically. Do you think it is possible?

I hope I made myself clear (English is not my first language). Let me know if you need me to explain things better! Thank you in advance. :)

```
if ($(window).width() > 599 ) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 550) { //if you scroll past the slider
            $("#main nav").addClass("white-menu");
        } else {
            $("#main nav").removeClass("white-menu"); //so it turns black again
        }
    });
} else {
    // add it automatically (the slider is hidden):
    $("#main nav").addClass("white-menu");
};
```

Comment: $(window).width() > "599" That's is wrong. You want an integer there. Remove quotes.

Comment: use .resize() https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Responsive web designs are usually done with @media tags in css.  Not to discourage you if this is just a practice exercise...

Comment: @DaseinA Whoops! Totally missed that. I fixed it now, thanks!

Comment: @Grumpy yes, I tried using that but it ended up looking worse. I don't really know how to use it properly.

Comment: @Brian Hahaha yes, I know! I'm actually using media queries too, but I just wanted to know how to do it using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use all the code inside scroll event

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 550 && $(this).width() <= 599) { //if you scroll past the slider
            $("#main nav").addClass("white-menu");
        } else {
            $("#main nav").removeClass("white-menu"); //so it turns black again
        }
    });
```

a similar [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f284943z/)

about resize you can use

```
$(window).on('resize',function() {
    $("#main nav").removeClass("white-menu");
});
```

on window resize the code will remove the class till user scroll then the scroll event will fire after user scrolling

or instead of all of that you can just use

```
$(window).on('scroll resize',function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 550 && $(this).width() <= 599) { //if you scroll past the slider
            $("#main nav").addClass("white-menu");
        } else {
            $("#main nav").removeClass("white-menu"); //so it turns black again
        }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f284943z/2/)

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your reply. This works perfectly! The only problem I'm having is that, when I resize the window, the menu mantains its color until I scroll. Do you know how can I fix that? Or perhaps it's just a bug of my browser.

*Edit*

Oh, I'm an idiot. Of course it won't work until I scroll if it's inside a scroll function. Sorry!

Comment: @Drake last update will be helpful .. please take a look at it with last DEMO

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly. I didn't know you could use `'scroll resize'`. :)

Comment: @Drake never mind .. I didn't know that too since a short time ago :) :) .. Good Luck :)

Answer (score 1):

`.scroll` allows you to listen to event, if you only listen when the window is the correct size, this listener won't get triggered if that changes, so I changed it around a bit:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 599 ) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 550) { //if you scroll past the slider
        $("#main nav").addClass("white-menu");
    } else {
        $("#main nav").removeClass("white-menu"); //so it turns black again
    }
  }
});
```

Like Brian mentioned you should use CSS for this other case:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  #main nav {
    // white-menu styles here
  }
}
```

For reference the JS way would be:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 599 ) {
    $("#main nav").addClass("white-menu");
  }
});
```

It also might be worth thinking about doing a throttle/debounce on these event listeners. They will get called a **lot** and if your JS starts to do anything more complicated you will see a performance hit. This example uses the [underscore library](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
var onScroll = function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 599 ) {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 550) { //if you scroll past the slider
        $("#main nav").addClass("white-menu");
    } else {
        $("#main nav").removeClass("white-menu"); //so it turns black again
    }
  }
}

// Don't run until the window has stopped being resized for at least 50ms
var debouncedOnScroll = _.debounce(onScroll, 50);

$(window).scroll(debouncedOnScroll);
```

See http://underscorejs.org/#debounce

Comment: Just as an additional side note, if you're invested in using JavaScript you can utilize the same functionality as @media using the .matchMedia API and then checking if it's truthy. http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries4.shtml

Comment: Thanks for this reply! It was very helpful and I will definitely learn more about underscore when I'm more comfortable using jQuery. :)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I used your code in a fiddle and it worked find. As it's state in another answer, the improve of your code will be using the scroll function to wrap all the actions:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    $("#main nav").toggleClass("white-menu", ($(window).scrollTop() >= 550 && $(window).width() <= 599));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply! I tried testing your code but it doesn't work. Perhaps there's something missing?

Comment: I don't know in which escenario you used it. It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/ysqks4wy/

Comment: Just remember to resize the frame so the code can be applied

Comment: There you go. Now you've learnt another method to switch classes in jquery ``toggleClass`` which spares you if else blocks to add and remove classes. More effective and fancier :)